# How to order a unique list based on 2 object attributes in Java

Tags: java, sorting, collections, unique

I have a list of objects I'm referring to as Artifacts.  I need to sort alphabetically by the "Name" attribute and in numerical order by an attribute that Artifact has called "Level".

The Level is not always set in Artifact and in that case the entire collection should be alphabetical.  If the Artifact has a Level then that takes precedence and should be sorted by order of Level.

The Artifacts need to be unique based upon the Name attribute. I could use a Set collection and override the equals method of the Artifact to sort Alphabetically.  However, when I want to sort by Level, the equals method relevant to Name will throw off the results of this sort.

What collections and object structure should I use to remain unique by Name but also be able to sort by Level?

Comment: You should give some examples to make it clear.

Comment: So if you have 2 million objects, and the last one has no level, you want to sort the whole collection on the name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to look at the [comparable interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and the [comparator interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).  Implement Comparable if this is the only way your objects can be compared, comparator otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I think `java.util.TreeSet` is good Container for your problem. It is Set and it uses Compareble mechanism.

So you have two options:

1) put Comparator into TreeSet constructor

2) make your Artifact implement Comparable

TIP: In compareTo method you can use compareTo method from String.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will sort the set giving the precedence to the level and later the name. If a level is null, it will be placed at the beginning, treating it as it was a level 0. For null names, the Artifact will be positioned as it had an empty level. Hope that helps.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Artifact implements Comparable<Artifact> {

private String name;
private Integer level;

public Artifact(String name, Integer level) {
    this.name = name;
    this.level = level;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((level == null) ? 0 : level.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Artifact other = (Artifact) obj;
    if (level == null) {
        if (other.level != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!level.equals(other.level))
        return false;
    if (name == null) {
        if (other.name != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
        return false;
    return true;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Artifact o) {
    if (level == null){
        return new Artifact(name, 0).compareTo(o);
    }

    if (name == null){
        return new Artifact("", level).compareTo(o);
    }

    if (level.equals(o.level)) {
        return name.compareTo(o.name);
    } else {
        return level.compareTo(o.level);
    }
}

public String toString() {
    return level + " " + name;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Artifact a1 = new Artifact("a", 1);
    Artifact a2 = new Artifact("a", 2);
    Artifact a3 = new Artifact("a", 3);
    Artifact b1 = new Artifact("b", 1);
    Artifact b2 = new Artifact("b", 2);
    Artifact b2a = new Artifact("b", 2);
    Artifact nullLevel = new Artifact("a",null);
    Artifact nullName = new Artifact(null,2);
    SortedSet<Artifact> set = new TreeSet<Artifact>();
    set.add(a1);
    set.add(a2);
    set.add(a3);
    set.add(b1);
    set.add(b2);
    set.add(b2a);
    set.add(nullLevel);
    set.add(nullName);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(set.toArray()));
}

}
```